# numpy: summing along all but last axis

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an `ndarray` of arbitrary shape and I would like to compute the sum along all but the last axis I can, for instance, achieve it by doing

```
all_but_last = tuple(range(arr.ndim - 1))
sum = arr.sum(axis=all_but_last)
```

Now, `tuple(range(arr.ndim - 1))` is not exactly intuitive I feel. Is there a more elegant/numpy-esque way to do this?

Moreover, if I want to do this for multiple arrays of varying shape, I'll have to calculate a separate dimension tuple for each of them. Is there a more canonical way to say "regardless of what the dimensions are, just give me all but one axis"?

Comment: Intuitive or not, I think this makes the best use of the `axis` parameter.  Hide it in a function, and noone will know the difference (and you can comment it).  `numpy` functions play this sort of 'game' frequently.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could reshape the array so that all axes except the last are flattened (e.g. shape `(k, l, m, n)` becomes `(k*l*m, n)`), and then sum over the first axis.

For example, here's your calculation:

```
In [170]: arr.shape
Out[170]: (2, 3, 4)

In [171]: arr.sum(axis=tuple(range(arr.ndim - 1)))
Out[171]: array([2.85994792, 2.8922732 , 2.29051163, 2.77275709])
```

Here's the alternative:

```
In [172]: arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1]).sum(axis=0)
Out[172]: array([2.85994792, 2.8922732 , 2.29051163, 2.77275709])
```

Comment: Is there a more generalizable method? I suppose you can do which was what I was looking for. 
`sums = arr.sum(axis=tuple(x for x in range(arr.ndim) if x!= MY_AXIS))`
Then `sums.shape` would just be `(MY_AXIS,)`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `np.apply_over_axes` to sum over multiple axes.

```
np.apply_over_axes(np.sum, arr, [0,2]) #sum over axes 0 and 2

np.apply_over_axes(np.sum, arr, range(arr.ndim - 1)) #sum over all but last axis
```

Comment: Isn't this just doing the same thing?  but in a slower way, iterating over the axes in Python code rather internally to `sum`?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure what you mean as far as iterating over all axis in python code because all methods shown here are using `range` for the axis extrapolation

Comment: But look at the code for `apply_over_axes` - it iterates on the `axes` parameter.  Timeit as well.

Comment: Even setting speed aside, what is the benefit of this over `sum(axis=...)`?

Comment: @hpaulj The above is hard to generalize to any axes, so for fast development, I used the slow running one.